Eas Expo development build succeeds but production build fails after upgrading to Expo v50
After upgrading expo to v50, Expo eas build --profile development-simulator --platform ios succeeds, and the app works well in the simulator.
Expo eas build --profile product --platform ios fails.
Any idea would be really helpful.
The fastlane log shows:
Executing expo-updates Pods/EXUpdates » [CP-User] Generate app.manifest for expo-updates

❌  error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')


❌ Metro encountered an error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')
Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/troubleshooting
› Packaging expo-constants Pods/EXConstants » libEXConstants.a
› Executing expo-constants Pods/EXConstants » Copy generated compatibility header

I tried using nove v16 and 18, and tweaks for metro.config.js, app.js, app.json...
eas.json includes:
      "extends": "base",
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "channel":"development",
      "releaseChannel": "default",
      //"node": "16.18.1",
      "env": {
        "ENVIRONMENT": "development-simulator"
      },
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true,
        "resourceClass": "m-medium",
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug",
        "cache": {
          "key": "160122"
        }
      },
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "extends": "base",
      "distribution": "store",
      "channel":"production",
      "releaseChannel": "stable",
      //"node": "16.18.1",
      "env": {
        "ENVIRONMENT": "production"
      },
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium",
        "buildConfiguration": "Release",
        "cache": {
          "key": "160122"
        }
      },
      "android": {
        "buildType": "app-bundle"
      }
    }

The xcode log includes:
/bin/sh -c /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/StarboardSail-fyjgtophwchzdcftzuumkhstlmnk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/StarboardSail/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/EXUpdates.build/Script-46EB2E00026AB0.sh
Node found at: /Users/expo/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.0/bin/node
Failed to construct transformer:  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/expo/workingdir/node_modules'
    at Object.statSync (node:fs:1690:3)
    at verifyRootExists (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:136:13)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at new Transformer (/Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:16:31)
    at /Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:14:29
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'stat',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/Users/expo/workingdir/node_modules'
}
error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')
Error: @build-script-error-begin
Error loading assets JSON from Metro. Ensure you've followed all expo-updates installation steps correctly. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')
@build-script-error-end

    at /Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-updates/scripts/createManifest.js:72:11
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Libtool /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/StarboardSail-fyjgtophwchzdcftzuumkhstlmnk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/StarboardSail/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/libEXConstants.a normal (in target 'EXConstants' from project 'Pods')

Again, any idea would be great. Thanks!
